# What costs should one take into account while planning a workshop?

Tags: research-proposal, workshop

Imagine an STEM-based (European or North American) grant proposal in the last phase of which a workshop is desired to be held in order to better disseminate research results among not only researchers but also relevant practitioners. I am wondering what expenses should be taken into account to estimate the overall cost of the workshop. Here is the list I have come up with so far:

- Travel, accommodation, and subsistence costs associated with any plenary speaker
- Compensation for activities like presentation and assignment preparation
- Snacks and refreshments

What other costs should one consider?

Comment: Will it be your own stand-alone workshop or do you plan to put a workshop proposal in to a (major) conference in your field? If you're proposing a workshop as part of a conference, then (in theory) you'll get a lot more "passing footfall", as people might be more likely to attend if they're at the conference anyway. But on the negative side, your participants will need conference tickets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need any additional staff? E.g. student helpers you have to pay?
Take into account that you do not only need them at the workshop itself, but also some days in advance and one day afterwards to clear everything up.

How will your workshop be advertised? Do you need flyers, posters, banners, a homepage?

Do you plan to give information material or gifts to the participants?

Edit: Perhaps you might want to invite your speakers to a dinner.
(In that case, make sure beforehand that these expenses are reimbursable in your grant, too.)

Answer (score 7):

Will you have to pay for the room(s) in which the workshop is held? What about projection equipment and blackboards?

It's fairly common for workshops to provide some travel support for some non-plenary speakers, especially junior researchers. You might as well ask for that in your grant proposal.